# When i trying for a form validate im getting this error (Property 'email' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}>')

Tags: react-native

```
    interface IRegisterProps {
  navigation: any;
}

interface IRegisterState { }


class RegisterScreen extends React.PureComponent<IRegisterProps, IRegisterState> {

  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      nick: "",
      nickError: ""
    };
  }
nickValidator(){
  if(this.state.mail=""){
    
  }
}
```

when im trying to do validate im geeting this error: Property 'email' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}>'

if(this.state.mail=""){ this is my error line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While comparing, you can't assign a value to variable,
use `==` instead

```
 if(this.state.mail==""){
```

Also please cross check if it's `mail` or `email` in your state and change the condition accordingly

Secondly, add property `email` to your state

```
this.state = {
  ...
 email: ''
};
```

or make it type of `any`

```
this.state: any = {
  ...
};
```

If you using interface in the state that define the property in the interface too

```
interface IRegisterState {
   email: string
}
```

Comment: im afraid same error again

Comment: If you using typescript, then you have to either provide the type `any` to state or use proper interface for state with all the values defined, in this case add email to state

Comment: updated the answer accordingly

Comment: i delete nick and add email in consturctor. bu again...

Comment: constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email: "",
      emailError: ""
    };
  }

Comment: As you using the state with interface IRegisterState, you have to define the email in this too

Comment: how can i define like that ?

Comment: see in the answer, added

Comment: i defind ing IRegisterState

Comment: omg it worked ty so much

Comment: glad to help, please consider accepting the answer and upvoting it